# java + replace small letters to capital letters in args

Tags: java

Please advice:

I write here part of JAVA language 
in args[0] could be capital letters as "A" "B" "C" or small letter
 as "a" "b" "d" "i"

my target is to replace all small letters in args[0] to capital letters
How to do that?

The second question – how to remove spaces in args[0] ?

example
           args[0] could be deuSFRCQAAAVTvtev3843d4;'p-03eudhAHAHS

```
       int[] anArray = new int[30];  

              anArray[0]= args[0].replaceAll("[^A]", "").length();
              anArray[1]= args[0].replaceAll("[^B]", "").length();
              .
              .
              .
              .
```

.
.

Comment: Try `System.out.println("deuSFRCQAAAVTvtev3843d4;'p-03eudhAHAHS".toUpperCase());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most pragmatic way would be:

```
String string = args[0].toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to remove spaces use this:

```
args[0] = args[0].replace(" ", "").toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29)

> **toUpperCase**
>
> `public String`**`toUpperCase()`**
>
> Converts all of the characters in this `String` to upper case using the rules of the default locale. This method is equivalent to: `toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault())`.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> the `String`, converted to uppercase.
>
> **See Also:**
>
> `toUpperCase(Locale)`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an all-uppercase version of a string, use [String.toUpperCase()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

> my target is to replace all small letters in args[0] to capital
>   letters How to do that?

There is a method on the [String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class called [`toUpperCase`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29).

You use it as

```
args[0].toUpperCase
```

> The second question – how to remove spaces in args[0] ?

There is another method in String called [`trim`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

You use it as

```
args[0].trim()
```

Comment: but if I have agrs as "addd xxyz" he take only the addd ?

Comment: I write in my program:   String string = args[0].toUpperCase();
  String stringfinal = string.trim();

Comment: 1. if you have args as `addd xxyz`, `addd` will be in `args[0]` and `xxyz` will be in `args[1]` - i.e., they are _two_ arguments

Comment: 2. `String string = args[0].toUpperCase(); String stringfinal = string.trim();` is fine. You can also do `String string = args[0].toUpperCase().trim();`

Comment: Note: trim() only removes spaces on the ends of the string http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()